# Adding example Titanium iOS Module in Titanium Test Application fails with 'Script Error = Couldn't find module:'

Tags: ios, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-modules

Just learning Appcelerator. As far as I discovered I can add a native framework project as a module in Appcelerator Application.

So I started with this link http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/iOS_Module_Development_Guide which was straightforward and everything worked nicely as I followed the tutorial till I tried to add the 'test' module which I named com.example.titanium into a test Titanium single window application.

Followed the exact steps and everything seemed OK, except the part that Titanium is smart enough to extract the zip file module into the appropriate modules folder, its not so smart after all :)

But OK figured out and completed the task, I can discover the module into the TiApp Editor and add it in the Modules section (tiapp.xml).

After so much happiness I ended up struggling half a day till I came here for my last hopes to find out why when trying to require the module which is added successfully into the application could not be found.

I require the app with these two lines of code as the tutorial suggests.

```
// After 
new Window().open(); 
// Added
var test = require('com.example.titanium'); 
Ti.API.info("module is => "+test);
// Tried before or whatever, nothing worked
```

After many readings in the same problem tried lots of alternate approaches. Adding the module per project, global, trying to add it into the $HOME/Library... not working, doesn't even have a folder about Titanium. other than that I created it and tried, everything built nicely with build.py no error occurred while following the tutorial.

I noticed though in the build process that the modules section is not took into consideration from Titanium Studio, you can see below the log that No Titanium modules are required, continuing.

```
Please report bugs to http://jira.appcelerator.org/ 
[INFO] : Build type: development 
[INFO] : Building for target: simulator 
[INFO] : Building using iOS SDK: 6.1
[INFO] : Building for iOS iPhone Simulator: 6.1 
[INFO] : Building for device family: iphone 
[INFO] : Building for iOS 6.1; using 4.3 as minimum iOS version 
[INFO] : Minimum iOS version: 4.3 
[INFO] : Debugging disabled 
[INFO] : Initiating prepare phase 
[INFO] : Forcing rebuild: /Users/gtas/Documents/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/TestApplicationWithModule/build/iphone/build-manifest.json does not exist 
[INFO] : Forcing rebuild: debugger.plist does not exist 
[INFO] : No Titanium Modules required, continuing 
[INFO] : Performing full rebuild 
[INFO] : Copying Xcode iOS files 
[INFO] : Creating Xcode project directory: /Users/gtas/Documents/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/TestApplicationWithModule/build/iphone/TestApplicationWithModule.xcodeproj 
[INFO] : Writing Xcode project data file: Titanium.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj 
[INFO] : Writing Xcode project configuration: project.xcconfig 
[INFO] : Writing Xcode module configuration: module.xcconfig 
[INFO] : Creating symlinks for simulator build 
[INFO] : Forcing rebuild: ApplicationDefaults.m has changed since last build 
[INFO] : Writing properties to ApplicationDefaults.m 
[INFO] : Compiling localization files 
[INFO] : No module resources to copy 
[INFO] : No CommonJS modules to copy 
[INFO] : Checking for Splash Screen localization 
[INFO] : Invoking xcodebuild 
[INFO] : Finished building the application in 30s 23ms 
[INFO] : Running application in iOS Simulator 
[INFO] : Launching application in iOS Simulator 
[INFO] : Application started [ERROR] : Script Error = Couldn't find module: com.example.titanium.
```

My goal is to add an existing Objective-C iOS native framework to the Titanium applications.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your module has not installed successfully or in a proper way. Please try the following steps after removing the module from your project

1. Copy your **.zip file(compiled and error free)** to the downloads folder
2. Open **terminal**
3. Change the directory to downloads as follows : `cd Downloads/`
4. install the module to the titanium library as follows

   `unzip -u -o com.example.titanium-iphone-1.2.6.zip -d ~/Library/Application\ Support/Titanium`
5. Go to **TiApp.xml**
6. Add the module to your project as in the picture
   [image]
7. **Clean your project** and run it..

I have used the above steps while installing the ios module to my project and It works perfect for me.. Try the above steps and I hope this will resolve your issue..

Comment: Thank you for you time and help. Problem was the type of the project I selected to test the 'com.example.titanium' module. I selected Single Window Application and it didn't worked. Then it hit me to just test it using a tabbed application and it worked perfectly. It seems so different between what the one project does while builds to the other.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the module manually or via Menu (Help -> Install Titanium Module)? You should prefer the second way. So please remove all your manually added modules everywhere you added them (global, project, etc...) because multiple installations (even if they are equal) can confuse the build management.

Now add the module - using the menu - to your project. Check tiapp.xml that everything is ok. If not then restart Titanium Studio and check again.

After that manually remove the build folder and do a Clean & Build in Titanium Studio. Then run the project again.

If this doesn't help provide the full `build.log` of your project.

Comment: Removed the module created with ./build.py from everywhere. Added via Help -> Install Titanium Module the module from the $HOME folder. I had to add the module in the tiapp.xml using the GUI, checked in xml, everything fine, removed the build folder, build, same error again, I just don't get it! (I added the module per project this time)

Comment: What is the exact name of the build.log file? I can't seem to find such a file into the build/iphone/build folder

Comment: Titanium SDK 3.0.2, iOS 5.0, XCode 4.6.1

Comment: I think it's not visible in Titanium Studio but it's located in your project root.

Comment: Strange, strange IT world :) Can't find it but I 'solved' the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the type of project. I was selected the Single Window Application Titanium Project type.

I chose a tabbed project and it was perfectly worked.

For a reason there is a significant difference between project types where I find bad.

Anyone knows why should enlighten us.